# running autocomplete code from function error: TypeError: this.source is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to get jquery autocomplete to run its code from a function.  The reason for this is that I have about 40 fields on the form that all run the same code so I wanted to avoid repeating code as much as possible.  I have code working on another site with exactly this syntax but on the current site I am working on it throws the error.  I dont think its the jquery version as the autocomplete actually works in its simplest form.

```
var srch = [{value:"11",label:"Gavin"},{value:"22",label:"Greg"}];

jQuery(function($) {
/* this line returns the error */
    $( "#mytext" ).autocomplete(); { test("mytext",srch); }
/* this line works */
//    $( "#mytext" ).autocomplete({ source: srch });
});

function test(code,src)
{
    $(code).autocomplete("option", "source", src);
    alert('test');
}
```

So when I run the page with the problem line of code uncommented the alert message displays when the page loads, which indicates that the function is being called correctly, however, when I enter the first character in the field, the error occurs.  If I comment this line out and run the other that doesnt use the function, it works fine.

This is driving me batty, its probably something very simple but im just not seeing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Greg J

Comment: You need to pass ID selector: `$( "#mytext" ).autocomplete();  test("#mytext",srch);` **OR** `$('#'+code)`  http://jsfiddle.net/L9tnu/

Comment: omg! that works! you know I thought I had tried that at some point but I guess I tried so many things I must have gotten mixed up about it.  thank you very much!